# aspnet membeship logon page and https redirect

Tags: redirect, https, asp.net-membership

I have a gridview control that has on onclick event bound to every cell. Once a user clicks on a cell it directs them to a booking confirmation page and passes 3 url variables. This booking page is behind a aspnet membership and thus if the user is not logged in they are served the login page. The login page has a redirect to https connection in the onload event using the IsSecure property. The issue is once the user logs in, then is returned to the booking confirmation page I lose 2 of the url vars.

If I remove the https redirect, everything works fine, but the user logs on on a http connection, which is not cool.

Appreciate and help

thanks

Reuben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short of some extra plumbing that would have to span several hops, your best bet is to stash the data in session until they come out of authentication.

Comment: Would I then need to call a client side script to process the vars from the gridview into session vars?

thanks

Comment: In the code behind of the actual target page, check for session vars and render them back out as you see fit.. If you need these values for clientscript then sure, put them back into the url, or render them into the page output. this was not part of the original question, defsol, and scope creep is just as annoying in SO as in RL. just sayin... lol ;-)

Comment: My apologies. Kinda of new around here and just learning to walk. I've alwyas thought there's a fine line between scope creep & natural progression.

Comment: @DefSol, you sure you are not in marketing or higher management? lol. Welcome to SO.